# SQLExpress database instance not commiting changes with local mdf db

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq, sql-server-express

I'm building my application using .NET.

I created a `SQLExpress` database instance using Visual Studio and connected to it using LINQ.

This is its connection string

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TicTacToeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

This database contains only one table named `Player`.

[image]

I coded a stored procedure to insert a player named `InsertPlayer`

This code is to insert a new player.

```
TicTacToeDBLINQDataContext context = new TicTacToeDBLINQDataContext();
int? id = 0;
context.InsertPlayer("player1", 0, 0, 0, DateTime.Now, ref id);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

The problem is nothing is committed in the database and no new record is added.

I figured out that there is an inner copy of the `.mdf` file in `bin/Debug` directory. 
This copy is being used to insert data in.

But when I select data it gives me data from the outer version

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ no errors...

Comment: can u get any record from db?

Comment: I figured out that there is an inner copy of the mdf file in bin/Debug directory. this copy is being used to insert data in. but when I select data it gives me data from the outer version

Answer (score 0):

check the Value of `Copy to Output Directory property` of your database [right click on `mdf` file and go to properties],  if it is `Copy always` change it to `Copy if newer`

Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817.aspx for more information

Comment: how you select data or check your insert success or not?

Comment: select data using sql express viewer (Server Explorer)

Comment: check insert success by view data directly after inserting it using a datagridview

Comment: are you reload\ rebind datagridview after insert?